# how to retrieve checkboxlist values for from table for the given particular ID 

Tags: c#, database, wcf

Table has only 2 fields: **VehicleID** and **FacilitiesID**. **FacilitiesID** is the checkbox list value. For each **vehicleID** I entered multiple **FacilitiesID** as separate data. Now I want to retrieve values from the table for the given **VehicleID**.. Give some logic how to retrieve?

Comment: Try to rewrite your question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an easy approach for you is to use LINQ or EntityFramework.
For that, you need to set up an entity model, using the Visual Studio wizards, and then perform a query like:

```
var vehicle = Vehicles.Where(v => v.VehicleId == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // replace 1 by the Id of the vehicle you want.
```

For more help, edit your question.

Best regards

Comment: Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.VehicleId == 1); does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following query:

```
Select * from tableName where vehicleID=@vehicleID
```

and bind the result of this query to CheckedListBox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya.. this query works in database, but i am getting problem in DataAccess layer only, i couldnt retrive values by passing 1 VehicleID value.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get u on ur problem.

Are u facing problem in getting the data to be displayed in the checkboxlist or any other thing ?

if u r not getting response for vehicle ID 1, then there might not be any record for this VehicleID value.

Comment: I ve checked, there s recods in the table for the vehicleID, I m using this storedProcedure "select FacilitiesID from VehicleFacilities where VehicleID=@VehicleID ", but its not fetching and passing values back to the data access layer..